# How MySQL handles IN predicates

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing

Suppose the table T has three columns,

```
 id int not null auto_increment,
 my_id int,
 name varchar(200).
```

and the query is "select * from T where my_id in (var_1, var_2, ..., var_n) and name = 'name_var'".

Is there any performance difference between below two indices?

- Index1: (my_id, name)
- Index2: (name, my_id).

Comment: that's a scary wide composite, ouch (times 2 no less)

Answer (score 1):

•Index1: (my_id, name)
•Index2: (name, my_id).

Yes, above two would slightly differ when it comes to query performance.

Always, the leftmost fields are the most important in determining the efficiency and selectivity of an index. 
index should be built on the column(s) which are frequently used in the WHERE, ORDER BY, and GROUP BY clauses. 
Hope this helps!

Comment: It would be great, if you update the answer with more elaboration.

Answer (score 0):

In a composite index, the column to be searched should appear first. So, if you are searching for a set of `id` values, you'll want `id` to show up first in the index.

But if `id` is the primary key and you're using a `SELECT *` clause to retrieve the whole row, it doesn't make sense to add another index.  The way tables are organized, all the data of the row appears clustered with each `id` value.   So just use the index on the primary key.

tl;dr:  neither `(id,name)` nor `(name,id)` will help this query.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I updated my question. my_id(previous id) is not primary key. The primary key is id which is auto increment.

Answer (score 0):

In general, it is best to start the `INDEX` with the `WHERE` clauses with `col = const`.  One range can come last.  `IN` is sort of like `=`, sort like a range.  Hence, this is best:

```
INDEX(name, id)
```

Think of it this way.  The index is an ordered list.  With this index, it will start at the `name=...` and then have to scan or leapfrog through all the ids with that name.

I suspect the `PRIMARY KEY` is not `(id)`.  If it were, why would you be checking the name?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I clarified my question. my_id(previous id) is not primary key. The primary key is id which is auto increment.